# How get IP address before connecting on server client (use websockets/ws)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

How get IP address before connecting on server client  (use websockets/ws)?

```
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 8081, verifyClient: function(info, callback) { });
```

Comment: If you want the IP address for some DNS name, then use a DNS lookup library.  If you want the IP address of something else, then please clarify your question as it is not very clear.

Comment: @jfriend00 I edit my question

Comment: I still don't know what you want the IP address of.

Comment: @jfriend00 IP address for client on server before connection

Comment: There is no client BEFORE a connection.  The server has no idea what client will connect in the future.  It could be any client in the world.

Comment: @jfriend00 get IP address for client on server before connection

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks You. I wanted to test the IP address to the blacklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the IP address of a client before it connects.  Before the connection, there is no contact at all between client and server and thus the server has no idea which client will connect some time in the future.  It would literally be any client in the world.

If you explain what you're really trying to accomplish we might be able to help you solve your problem better.

Comment: I wanted to test the IP address to the blacklist on server.

Comment: @gilo1212 - You let it connect, then check the IP address, then drop the connection if its on the blacklist or you use a proxy or firewall that can block it before it gets to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for client's IP address. One of the ways to get it

`websocket._socket.remoteAddress`

Comment: The OP wants that BEFORE connecting.

Comment: I use - `ws._socket.remoteAddress;`  But it worked after connection client on server.  ` /...../ webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
            ip = ws._socket.remoteAddress; /.........../`

Comment: Ah. I see you comment now. There is no client before connecting. I'd however assume again that he wants the IP address to check something. May be white-listing or something else.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes - Yes)